# php image type, mozila and IE7

Tags: php

i insert image in page and strangely I get a picture of the types.

show type with: $_FILES['img']['type'].

Result:

```
Firefox: image/jpeg
IE7: 'image/pjpeg'

Firefox: image/png
IE7: image/x-png
```

Now i use this filter:

```
$type_filter = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/bmp', 'image/x-png', 'image/pjpeg');
```

It is good, or something else is missing?
Thanks

Comment: I take it you are uploading files, hence you're use of $_FILES. Using $_FILES['img']['type'] is gonna give you what PHP says it is, not what your array says it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
if(stristr($_FILES['image']['type'], "image")){
enter code here
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks ;) but i wish allowed only: png, jpg, gif and bmp images type